# Is it possible to carryover data in the session?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise

Let's imagine I'm not logged in, and the server stores something in the session, like

`session[:color] = blue`

Is is possible to keep the setting for the user after logging in? It seems that after I login I get a new session id, and the setting is lost.

I'm using Rails 3.2.5 and Devise 2.1.0

Comment: @Tempus I guess not and your find are correct after logged one get new session id may you could employ some key store database like `redis` or something like to store the session value in them for a specific user and on login of that write that value session object again

Comment: @Tempus Or You could just use cookie for that matter I you feel using key store is way too much for this task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We used a cookie and it solved the problem.